# Error messages of two sample t test/ txt file dataset

Tags: r, encoding, statistics

I got an error message after I used t.test() on my datasets. The dataset is a txt file, the t.test function works well on other types of datasets like dat and csv

**Here's my code:**

```
petro <- read.table(file.choose(), header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
head(petro)

# two independent sample t test
t.test(petro$Canberra, petro$Perth, var.equal = TRUE)
```

After I run the t.test function, the error message was like:

```
*Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * abs(mx)) stop("data are essentially constant") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In var(x) : NAs introduced by coercion*
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show some summary statistics for `petro$Canberra` and `petro$Perth` the function is complaining because there is not a lot of variation in your data. Example: `t.test(rep(1,100), rep(1, 100))`

Comment: Okk so I used summary(petro$Canberra), it returns Length 20, Class: character, Class character

Comment: And summary(petro$Perth) returns Length 0, Class: Null, Mode: Null, which is incorrect as both sample numbers of Perth and Canberra should be 20

Comment: Please show us the output of `head(petro)`. If I had to guess there's a problem with your data, or the variable names. `read.table()` might be failing you here or your header might be shifted such that you're using the right name, but there's no data in the column because of how it's being read in. Are you sure it's tab-separated?

Comment: Try sep = ' ' in your read.table code.

Comment: Please replace image with output of `dput(petro)`.